# Update Java version of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, version, updates

the result of

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

in Eclipse gives back "1.8.0_05", but when I do "Java -version" in cmd under Windows 7, I get "1.8.0_25". What do I have to do in order to get eclipse also using that most updated version?

Under "right click on project -> properties -> Java Compiler" there's only "Java 1.8"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open 'Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs'. Update (or add) the Java 8 JRE to the current version of Java 8.

Also look at 'Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments' and make sure 'JavaSE-1.8' is set to the latest Java 8 (you may have to close and reopen the preferences before doing this).

Comment: Thanks! I did open 'Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs' and then edited the path to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25 (before it was just C:\Program Files\Java\jre8)